# Как передать файл на сервер с помощью socket.io-file-client если нету HTMLInputElement?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Требуется использовать пакет socket.io-file-client для загрузки файлов через SocketIO(WebSocket)
Для загрузки файлов используется метод upload, но он в качестве файла принимает аргумент элемента файла(HTMLInputElement). Но у меня нет возможности передать файл в таком виде просто потому что то что я пишу будет работать без сайта а в качестве обычного скрипта Node JS.
Вопрос, как передать файл на сервер с помощью socket.io-file-client если нету HTMLInputElement?

Comment: Если у вас не будет клиента, а только сервер, то откуда вы собираетесь передавать файл?

Comment: @SwaD
Требуется написать только клиент, сервер имеется, файлом будет картинка

Comment: Что у вас будет выступать в роли клиента?

Comment: @Swad В роли клиента выступает мой софт на NodeJS в котором как раз нужно реализовать передачу файла через socket.io-file-client

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось переписать пакет socket.io-file-client
Ранее там использовался FileReader, убрал его и оставил работу с буфером
В upload теперь просто передаю имя файла а далее с помощью fs.readFile получаю буфер